# Taskbar icon for the installed WPF application is missing in Windows 10 anniversary update OS

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, windows-10, taskbar

Icon is set in MainWindow.xaml of a WPF application.
If the application is Run as administrator then the Taskbar icon is visible, 
if it is run without administrator mode then it doesn't show.
This issue exists only if **Always, hide labels** is selected in **Combine taskbar buttons combobox** like below in settings page--

[image]

Operating System: Windows 10,
Version Number : 1607(OS build 14393.479).
**The same issue doesn't exist in Windows 7, 8 and windows 10(Before anniversary update).**
Any suggestions/Solutions to this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Icon is set in MainWindow.xaml of a WPF application' => code please

Comment: <Window  x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
Code is similar to this. Icon is set in         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"   Icon="pack://application:,,,/Application;component/Resources/icon.ico">

Icon is set in
 **startup Project** properties-->**Application** Tab--> **Resources** group--> **Icon and manifest** --> **Icon**

Comment: @tolanj, any update on the solution?